# Strange transpile error with RxJS5 Subject/Subscription

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, typescript2.0

I have this function:

```
const subs: Array<Subscription> = [];

const startActions = function () {

  const db = client.db('local');

  const delSub = del.subscribe(function (v: OplogDoc) {

     // ...
  });

  const insertSub = insert.subscribe(function (doc: OplogDoc) {

      // ...
  });

  const updateSub = update.subscribe(function (doc: OplogDoc) {

       // ... 
  });

  subs.push(
    delSub,
    insertSub,
    updateSub
  );
};
```

I am getting this transpilation error:

[image]

Here is the type:

```
export type SubjectMap = {
  [key: string]: Subject<Object>,
  all: Subject<any>,
  update: Subject<Object>,
  insert: Subject<Object>,
  delete: Subject<Object>,
  errors: Subject<Object>,
  end: Subject<Object>,
  del: Subject<Object>
}
```

so `delSub`, `insertSub`, and `updateSub` should all have the same type...anyone know what might be going on here?

UPDATE:

Did some more investigation. The type checking seems to only occur for the first argument to Array.prototype.push, and in that case, all the subscriptions fail, but now I see this fun one:

[image]

Comment: An error like that usually implies that you have more than one `rxjs` installation within your `node_modules` hierarchy. Run `npm list rxjs` to see what's in there.

Comment: @cartant good thinking, yep, 5.3.x and 6.0.0...is there any way to avoid this problem given two different versions? one is a straight dep, and one is a dep of a dep. You'd think the former would get full precedence.

Comment: Not really. If different dependencies need different versions, there's not much you can do about it. That said, some effort has gone into getting parallel installs to play nice with one another. If those efforts have not been backported to the lastest v5, you might still hit upon internal `instanceof` problems. You could solve your TypeScript problem by using `SubscriptionLike` (if your code is v6) or `ISubscription` (if your code is v5) as your array type - instead of `Subscription`, which is a class.

Comment: For the internal problems, see [#3544](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3544) and related issues/PRs.

Comment: Is #3544 in RxJS or TS or NPM? links help all people not just me thx

Comment: Actually, it was [#3477](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3477) and [#3476](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3476) that I was thinking of.

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3544

Comment: @cartant thank you - this seems to be a problem more fundamental to NPM and TS, than to RxJS, do you know if TS can do anything more? RxJS is just patching the problem by minimizing differences between versions, that's not really a solution IMO.

Comment: For using v5 and v6 together, those latter changes need to be made to `stable`, too - otherwise, you will see further problems. If that hasn't happened and you have problems with using v5 and v6, I'd suggest opening an issue. They aren't changes for TypeScript; the are for runtime, `instanceof` differences.

Comment: Well see my above comment - this isn't really RxJS's fault AFAICT. Seems to more of an issue with TS/NPM.

Comment: In other words, if I am using  `"skipLibCheck": true` in my `tsconfig`, why would TS ever look at more than the 1 version of RxJS installed at the top level?

Comment: ahhh this might happen if libraries are linked with NPM link

Comment: `skipLibCheck` skips the checking of the libraries' internal declarations. It doesn't skip the checking of the usage of the libraries' types in your code. `SubscritionLike` and `ISubscription` would be compatible, as they have compatible shapes. But `Subscription` is a class and there are two constructors and they are deemed different.